# iTunes Connect Distribution of older Build/Version

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

In iTunes Connect, under the Activity - All builds, I can see all the versions uploaded to the iTunes Connect. But I am not able to distribute an older version for internal testing.

Under the TestFlight - Select Version => I can see only the last version, but not any from the previous ones.

From iTunes Connect:

> Internal testers have access to the latest build for the selected version. They’ll also have access to any new builds that you upload for this version.

I would like to ask whether it is possible to distribute an older version via TestFlight.

Thank you for any help.

Best
Matti

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you the builds older than 60 days? if so they cannot. They expire at this time. If they are less than 60 days you should be able to select that build.

Comment: Yes, the builds are older than 60 days. We used an older version distributed via crashlytics. Thank you.